# Is there a math library that takes advantage of the new features in Visual C++ 2012

Tags: visual-c++, math, optimization, parallel-processing, visual-studio-2012

There are a number of new features for parallel programming in VS 2012 C++ compiler:

- Auto-parallelizer
- C++ Accelerated Massive Parallelism (AMP)
- Task Parallelism
- and more ...

I would like to see these applied to matrices multiplication, eigenvalue decomposition, etc. I mean everything that can benefit executing in parallel.

Is there such C++ library?

Vectorization is applied by default, so we skip this part.
The library will not be portable, so we skip this also.

Comment: The problem is that any library with a *serious* emphasis on performance already does all those things manually. So there's no need for the compiler to do it. In fact, these so-called "fancy" features often get in the way of optimization. It's basically like, "If you can't do it properly, then get out of the way so I can do it manually". This is why stuff like auto-parallelization is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Intel MKL.  I don't know about the specifics of the library but it doesn't hurt to investigate it.